# Why does my query in views.py give me a a TypeError?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am getting the following error when visiting a user review page:

```
TypeError at /reviews/ben/
show_reviews() got an unexpected keyword argument 'username'
```

However, when I run the same query (ie;     b = UserReview.objects.all, print b) in django console, everything prints and I can see all of the reviews that have been posted.  I'm not sure if I just made a simple mistake in my show_reviews() method or if the problem runs deeper than that.  Here is my code.

## models.py

```
class UserReview(models.Model):
    name= models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='usersbeingreviewed', null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='reviewauthors')
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    stars = models.IntegerField(max_length=5)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return u'%s %s %s %s %s' % (self.name, self.author, self.pub_date, self.stars, self.comment)
```

## urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r"^reviewseller/(?P<test>\w+)/$", get_review),
    url(r"^reviews/(?P<username>\w+)/$", show_reviews))
```

## views.py

```
def get_review(request, test):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        p = UserReviewForm(request.POST)
        testname = User.objects.get(username=test)
        if p.is_valid():
            reviewform=p.save(commit=False)
            reviewform.name=testname
            reviewform.author=request.user
            reviewform.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

def show_reviews(request):
    latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.all()
    context1 = {'latest_reviews': latest_reviews}
    return render(request, 'reviews.html', context1)
```

## forms.py

```
class UserReviewForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = UserReview
         fields = ['stars', 'comment']
         widgets = {
         'comment': Textarea,
         'stars': RadioSelect(choices=[
             (1, 'Very poor'),
             (2, 'Poor'),
             (3, 'Satisfactory'),
             (4, 'Great'),
             (5, 'Excellent')
             ])
         }
```

I was earlier running into another problem where the ReviewSeller form was saving the username string rather than the user instance, so I don't know if these are related issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the configured url:

```
url(r"^reviews/(?P<username>\w+)/$", show_reviews)
```

you are capturing `username` from the URL. Your view should have it as an argument:

```
def show_reviews(request, username):
    ...
```

Comment: (or remove it from the URL, since it's not used in the view.)

Comment: @DanielRoseman yeah, I was not sure what the OP was trying to achieve. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I think should be putting latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.get(username=username)

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia are you trying to pull all reviews for the `username` being reviewed?

Comment: yes.  so latest_reviews = UserReview.objects.get(name=username) ?

Comment: @Dr.Donnaloia nope, you should use `UserReview.objects.filter()` and check for `User`'s name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65051/discussion-between-dr-donnaloia-and-alecxe).